# Replacing custom characters during string.split()

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have a fairly large javascript/html application that updates frequently and receives a lot of data. It's running very quickly and smoothly but I need to now introduce a function that will have to process any incoming data for special chars, and I fear it will be a lot of extra processing time (and jsperf is kinda dead at the moment).

I will make a request to get a .json file via AJAX and then simply use the data as is. But now I will need to look out for strings with #2C (hex comma) because all of the incoming data is comma-separated values.

**in File.json**

```
{
  names: "Bob, Billy",
  likes : "meat,potatoes
}
```

Now I need

```
{
  names: "Bob, Billy",
  likes : "meat#2Cbeear#2Cwine,potatoes
}
```

where #2C (hex for comma) is a comma within the string.

I have this code which works fine

```
var str = "a,b,c#2Cd";

var arr = str.split(',');

function escapeCommas(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].indexOf("#2C") !== -1) {
            var s = arr[i].replace("#2C", ',');
            arr[i] = s;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(escapeCommas(arr));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hogf5me/1/

I have a lot of functions that process the JSON data often as

```
var name = str.split(',')[i];
```

I am wondering how I could extend or re-write .split to automatically replace #2C with a comma.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why don't you directly replace the `#2C` with the comma, without using `split` ?

Comment: Please check updated answer

Comment: @Cristy Because that would create another comma, which would create another index in the array, which is totally different data.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I think this is better:

```
var j = {
  names: "Bob, Billy",
  likes : "meat#2Cpotatoes"
};
var result = j.likes.replace(/#2C/g, ',');
// j.likes.replace(/#2C/ig, ','); - if you want case insensitive
// and simply reverse parameters if you want
console.log(result);
```

This was my initial approach:

```
var j = {
  names: "Bob, Billy",
  likes : "meat,potatoes"
}
var result = j.likes.split(",").join("#2C")

console.log(result);
// meat#2Cpotatoes
```

Or if you have it the reverse:

```
var j = {
  names: "Bob, Billy",
  likes : "meat#2Cpotatoes"
}
var result = j.likes.split("#2C").join(",")

console.log(result);
// meat,potatoes
```

Comment: I need to replace the #2C after the split, otherwise it will alter my data. The #2C is essentially an escaped comma so that .split() does not interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated to reflect feedback] - try at http://jsfiddle.net

```
var str = 'a,b,c#2Cd,e#2Cf#2Cg';

alert(str.split(',').join('|')); // Original

String.prototype.native_split = String.prototype.split;
String.prototype.split = function (separator, limit) {
    if ((separator===',')&&(!limit)) return this.replace(/,/g,'\0').replace(/#2C/gi,',').native_split('\0');
    return this.native_split(separator, limit);
}
alert(str.split(',').join('|')); // Enhanced to un-escape "#2C" and "#2c"

String.prototype.split = String.prototype.native_split;
alert(str.split(',').join('|')); // Original restored
```

Couple minor tangential notes about your function "escapeCommas": this function is really doing a logical "un-escape" and so the function name might be reconsidered. Also, unless it is your intention to only replace the first occurence of "#2C" in each item then you should use the "g" (global) flag, otherwise an item "c#2Cd#2Cde" would come out "c,d#2Ce".

Comment: Sorry, I guess no one understood I need to .replace after .split as to not add any new commas.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I have now updated my response to augment my answer as to how you could "extend or re-write .split" to also have a functional split implementation that exactly matches your need.